# Is there a system that supports playing really high-powered characters for a Dragon Ball Z scenario?

Tags: game-recommendation, system-for-setting

What's the best game system for role-playing characters that are *incredibly* powerful?

For example, a low-powered character in such a system should be able to take a few seconds and destroy Earth's moon from Earth, while a high-powered character should possess power over *one million times* more powerful than that.

A recommended system should...

- provide guidelines for adjudicating characters with such overwhelming power.
- offer examples of adventures such characters would undertake.

I am interested in the fighting aspects of the game (stats, how combat works, how levels work, etc.)

---

I'm looking for a system that supports *DBZ* characters with rules for concrete powers and their effects. Nothing too abstracted, and definitely not a narrative-centric set of rules.

Upon hearing of the *DBZ* sequel coming out (*Dragonball Super*), I'm rewatching the *DBZ* series and trying to figure out how to emulate the kinds of abilities they have in a tabletop RPG. The [*DBZ Anime Adventure Game*](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_The_Anime_Adventure_Game) has received terrible reviews and isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: As usual, you should only answer a game-rec if you have done that or seen it done (Good Subjective).  "I like game X and am sure it can do it even though I haven't done that" is deletable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a few games that mechanically support the kind of play you're looking for, though I don't think anything really gives good advice to capture the DBZ feel specifically.

**Marvel Super Heroes RPG (from the 80s)**

The old school [Marvel Super Heroes RPG](http://www.classicmarvelforever.com/cms/) scaled quite a bit.  The hard part is that the top ranks begin to condense quite a bit of range.  You could easily hack the system to either consider lower ranks to be higher ("You can blow up the moon at Excellent Rank") or you can consider the various point differences within the highest ranks as worth exploring.  The retroclone [FASERIP](http://www.gratisgames.webspace.virginmedia.com/faserip.html) version of MSH looks pretty good in general if you want something accessible.

I have mostly run MSH at medium-to medium-high superhero levels - the highest ranks (Shift X, etc.) haven't shown up in the games I've run, though I know the core game basically isn't designed to run at that level - which is why I think reskinning the lower ranks is going to hold up better than dealing with everyone floating at the top ranks.  Just reduce the material strength of everything, including planets.

**Hero Wars/Hero Quest**

The core game system supports everything from normal people to gods, so it naturally can easily support DBZ action as well.  Hero Wars and Hero Quest 1 actually used the idea of scaling quite well.  HQ2 went in a different direction and abandoned the value of scaling for... a more abstract simulation of success/failure modeling.

I ran a DBZ game for a couple of sessions using the original Hero Wars - because the game has very abstract "Adventure Points", it does rely a bit on creative input from the group to keep the attacks exciting and interesting.  HW/HQ works really well for having stuff like characters encourage each other, or get a bonus for being outraged about having their friends hurt.

**Mythender**

The premise of [Mythender](http://mythenderrpg.com/) is "You kill gods" and the game is easily hacked to being any kind of uber force or god.  Which is pretty much how all of the arcs of DBZ go.  ("Oh wait, here's this thing that's WORSE").

I haven't run or played Mythender yet, so this is a speculative suggestion based on looking at the rules and it's examples of who play runs.

**DBZ Tropes to consider**

Pretty much whatever system you use, most of the power disparity issues are... well, plot points rather than tactical realities when you follow the appropriate tropes:

1. The uber bad guy never kills everyone/destroys the planet outright even though that would be the easy/smart thing to do.
2. The uber bad guy loves to spend a lot of time bragging, tormenting people, etc. which is tactically stupid.
3. The uber bad guy loves to give people a chance to train, or leaves people without confirming the kill.
4. The good guys will always be able to train up to being able to win, or, through the power of rage/love of friends/personal break through, magically become powerful enough to win at the last second.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on what experience you have with each of these systems using them in the same type of scenario the question is asking about?

Comment: +1 for considering the tropes of DBZ when recommending a game: it is something that a lot of people tend to forget with game reccomendation.

Comment: Those first three tropes don't really happen in Dragon Ball Z though.  Bad guys *do* try to kill everyone on the planet, bad guys *do* attack and kill strategically, and when the heroes have a chance to train, it's because the bad guy doesn't *know* about it, not because they 'gave them a chance' (with the sole exception in all these cases of Perfect Cell, because he specifically wanted to fight them at their strongest to prove they never stood a chance, before destroying the world).

Comment: You should... probably rewatch/re-read the series.  Raditz: pointless gloating.  Vegeta: pulls out the Saibamen. Waits for Goku to show up.  Frieza waits a good while before calling in the Ginyu Force. etc.  It's classic plot escalation tropes and DBZ is full of them.  If you don't put it in your game, you may find your games ending very shortly.

Answer (score 4):

I think [Anima, Beyond Fantasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anima:_Beyond_Fantasy) can be a good set of rules for a Dragon Ball setting, provided most of them play with Tao or Technician. Most definitely not the story or the setting, since it doesn´t go the way DBZ goes.

That said, Anima works on levels status very similar to [Rolemaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolemaster), it is mechanically possible for all characters to create a set of techniques that allow them to create a set of special powers and abilities that they can use consuming a thing named Ki. Never the less, Technicians and to a certain level, Taos, excel at this. Said techniques are heavily based on different anime series (overall Naruto, but including a lot of DBZ).
In game systems, Technicians receive bonus points for the Ki abilities (divided between two things called Martial Knowledge and Accumulation Multiple) and Taos receive bonuses to martial arts (from which you can choose quite a lot and it is specifically designed to mix them) which incedentally adds more Martial Knowledge to your character to buy more Ki stuff.

The mechanics of the game are quite extensive  but basically each technique has a level between 1 and 3 (again, easily extended for more levels) that costs an amount of points of martial knowledge to create and a cost on Ki points to use (which you must accumulate during combat with your Accumulation Multiple), what you can do with these techniques is realy up to you, since the creation of the technique is REALLY extensive, and you have from the basics more actions, more hit% and more damage, to supernatural shields, teleportation, estate-based attacks... the beauty is that you can combine them to create your unique technique. It is not narrative, since there are tons of tables to build and points to spend to do it correctly. It takes some use to, because for starters sometimes it feels overwhelming, but they are detailed and quite precise.

The good thing about level based is that you can quickly create powerful and not so powerful characters. It is true that the power levels you are talking about are not the typical bread and butter of the Anima campaigns, but you can do it with the system at hand. Your characters will definitely be above level 10 and technically the cap level is 20, but it is very easy to set no limit in levels since you just have to keep adding up.

All the game system is very friendly to anime stories, which is why I think it is a good choice. It is even possible, due to how the system works, that your characters require to spend some turns just charging up their Ki (which in DBZ they do often).

To give you an idea on how power levels work, there are rules for high level characters (I am talking of level 6 and above, not even reaching 10!) to fight armies of soldiers, by themselves. This is because levels give you caps on the amount of atk/def you can have, the good thing of techniques is that they avoid that cap, so usually high level technicians are one of the most feared things in the setting.

The adventures your characters will have are way out of the scope of the Anima usual game, so no help in there, but I do believe you already have an idea of the adventures you want to run. I should use Anima only for the game mechanics.

In terms of experience, I have reached a level 9 psionic (technically one of the worst classes at high levels) and I stood my ground against 500 soldiers! (which, admittedly, my Technician companion just grinded through, once he accumulated the Ki requiered...)

[Bilingual Bonus](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BilingualBonus): As you may know, Anima is a game created in Spain, so most of it´s fan base is spanish talking. In the [official site](http://www.edgeent.com/ir_al_mensaje/22468-conversiones_al_anime-26713) you can see an approach to most of the characters in DB-DBZ saga (divided by saga). Even more, in an [interview](http://www.koi-nya.net/2013/04/22/entrevista-a-carlos-garcia-creador-de-anima-beyond-fantasy/) with the author he crealy stated that this game is designed to play [Shonen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dnen) like (and I quote)  "Dragon Ball or Naruto, Berserk... or even Sailor Moon."

Even (yet!) more, the expansion book ´Dominus Exxet´(the expansion for technicians and taos) clearly states what I have said, in page 1 you can find:

> With these rules it is possible to emulate any fantasy world, be they
>   from books, video games, or animated series. Mythical mangas like
>   Dragon Ball, Bleach, or Naruto, or games like Final Fantasy, Street
>   Fighter, or Devil May Cry are easily adaptable with the Techniques and
>   abilities that appear here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest Mutants and Masterminds (3e).

It's power level system can handle a wide variety of character power levels, and at higher levels the characters can certainly be world shattering. Every power is discrete, but customisable. As an added bonus, a strength boosting power with the activation flaw can simulate going super-saiyan.

Character creation is point buy, and you level up by getting more points. It's a d20 system, and damage in particular should work very well. You roll a toughness check, with a dc based on the power level of the incoming attack. Fail a little, and you take penalties to your toughness for the rest of the fight (and some other conditions if you fail by a middle amount) These build until they fail by a large amount and that big hit finally drops them. Very anime.

Also, while I haven't run M&M for Dragonball, I have for fun made every single Fairy Tail character's powers. This thing can handle anime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Anima Prime.

Anima Prime is a game system that aims to emulate Final Fantasy style combats, where you spend turns filling up charge bars to later download special moves upon your enemies, which is sometimes a trope in DB.

Characters are hard to truly kill. Defeating them in combat merely makes them unable to contribute for the scene, and enemies can be harmed in different ways depending if they're a mass of mobs, a squad or a solo boss, which also is how Goku and friends usually deal with troops, powerful elites and arc end bosses.

Combat involves a lot of description around three themes chosen by the player, which might be an inconveninece. Most DBZ characters whose power level is high enough usually rely on the same tactics: brute force, speed and martial prowess. The system might need someone familiar with DBZ to tweak the list of available approaches to match the subtle differences between characters.

Combat moves can be anything and easily conform to the Aesthetics of the group. An enemy could charge his moves by standing still and unnoticed after being beaten up, another might hide behind a ninja tarp and wait for the enemy to come looking from him. And, despite not having fusion mechanics, there are ways to engineer coordinated attacks baked right into the system (even if in my gaming group we didn't find them that effective).

Some options, like (in Final Fantasy words) materia infused weapons you can ignore (barring out some possible builds) or refluff (instead of a weapon that can be disarmed, it's a power you can disrupt).

Finally, characters are the best that there is, capable of incredible feats and virtually unstoppable out of combat, which ultimately becomes the way enemies use to stop the heroes. Very DBish if you ask me.